# I would like my SQL Result to return normal text instead of SQL format

Tags: node.js, postgresql

So when I run my application with: `node app.js user2` I get a SQL Format response which I DO NOT want. My other problem is when I try checking if 'user2' is Admin it will say its not even tho in my Database it is. Here is an example of what I want...

**I would like it to Log:**

```
user2 is admin
Admins: user2
```

Here is what I keep getting...

**I Do not want to Log:**

```
user2 is not admin
Result {
  command: 'SELECT',
  rowCount: 1,
  oid: null,
  rows: [ { username: 'user2' } ],
  fields: 
   [ Field {
       name: 'username',
       tableID: 16398,
       columnID: 2,
       dataTypeID: 25,
       dataTypeSize: -1,
       dataTypeModifier: -1,
       format: 'text' } ],
  _parsers: [ [Function: noParse] ],
  _types: 
   TypeOverrides {
     _types: 
      { getTypeParser: [Function: getTypeParser],
        setTypeParser: [Function: setTypeParser],
        arrayParser: [Object],
        builtins: [Object] },
     text: {},
     binary: {} },
  RowCtor: null,
  rowAsArray: false }
```

**My Code is...**

```
const net = require('net');
const fs = require('fs');
const request = require('request');

const pg = require('pg');
const conString = 'postgres://user_1:test123@localhost:5432/websocks';

const client = new pg.Client(conString);
client.connect();

const username = client.query('SELECT username FROM websocks.users');
const userData = client.query('SELECT id, username, password, rank FROM websocks.users');
const isAdmin = client.query('SELECT username FROM websocks.users where rank = 1');

isAdmin.then(function(result) {
  if (process.argv[2] === result) {
    console.log(process.argv[2]  + ' is admin!');
  } else {
    console.log(process.argv[2] + ' is not admin');
  }
  console.log("Admins: " + result);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if i understand well your first question is about  how to retrieve data from client.query. 
Well  for this query for example `const userData = client.query('SELECT id, username, password, rank FROM websocks.users');` postgres will return a array (list of resultset converted in a  array of object by a  PG  node library). You already have the result. You have to retrieve  "rows" attibute from the result this way  :

```
userData.then(result => {
 const usersDataArray = result.rows ;
 usersDataArray.foreach (row => {
       console.log (row.id);
       console.log (row.username);
       console.log (row.password);
    });
});
```

Same thing for your second question.  ClientQuery return a wrapped objet that containe the real result of the query.
To retrieve the  real result you must access to the rows attribute of this objet. 
this should  work :

```
isAdmin.then(function(result) {
    //i suppose that user with the rank 1 are admin so if the query return at least one result, that mean there is an admin in the database
    if (  result.rows.length > 0 ) {
      console.log(result.rows[0].username  + ' is admin!');
    } else {
      console.log(process.argv[2] + ' is not admin');
    }
    console.log("Admins: " );
    console.log( result.rows);
  });
```